# Azure Data factor error Copy activity encountered an unknown server error

Tags: azure, factory, vpn, azure-data-factory

We configure a new Azure Data factory to sync data from onpremises database to Blob storage following the steps as per [this link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-onpremises-datasources/)

The only deviation in step is we are connecting to SQL server on different domain using VPN. Using SSMS we are able to connect to the Database and query database.

We get error following error:

> Copy activity encountered an unknown server error: Code: 0 ; Message: 'Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=The user name or password is incorrect,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.

Is there any possible to enable additional logs to verify why are we getting this error. Any know scenario when we get this error?

Comment: `The user name or password is incorrect,` would seem to be a pretty good indicator of what is going wrong.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, in the data factory configuration I am providing the Same credential as used to accesses the database through SSMS..
After looking i event viewer stack trace is as below, not sure what is getting messed up with this WindowsCredentialUtil

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.NativeMethods.WindowsCredentialUtil.GetHandle(String userName, SecureString password)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SqlProviderHandler.PrepareConnection()..

Comment: Please dont use the comments for error messages or code.  If its relevant to the post, edit the post and put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event View, locate to Applications and Services Logs\Data Management Gateway, and check the detailed errors.

Comment: Thanks Samuel for the response.
After looking at the Event Viewer i get more details about the source of the error but still not able to get why is this error getting throwed

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.NativeMethods.WindowsCredentialUtil.GetHandle(String userName, SecureString password)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SqlProviderHandler.PrepareConnection()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SqlTabularSource.GetReader()

Comment: This does not attempt to solve the problem, it only tells OP where to look for more detail about his problem.  IOW, this is not an answer, it should be a comment.